# Why does setting Edge profile results in an error in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to run Whatsapp web without scanning QR code every time, thus I passed a profile of Edge so that it automatically detects the previous session without asking to scan it again.
Here's my code:

```
import cv2
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import threading as thread
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge


option = EdgeOptions()
option.use_chromium = True
option.add_argument("--headless")
option.add_argument('user-data-dir= C://Users//USERNAME//AppData//Local//Microsoft//Edge SxS//User Data')
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="J://edgedriver_win64//msedgedriver.exe",options = option)

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
```

But I am getting an error:

> File "h:\Huzaifa\Python\Project\OpenCV\Spam1.py", line 19, in 
> driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="J://edgedriver_win64//msedgedriver.exe",options
> = option) TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'

I tried running it headless and things but it just won't work.
Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the version of your selenium

Comment: It's 3.7.1 but the web tools I downloaded are of 3.4.1 edge webtools

Answer (score 0):

it could be a selenium version issue. The version of selenium you are using do not support the `options` argument. You can see the documentation for Firefox object that you're using by starting a Python console and:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
help(Firefox)
```

Comment: I'm using microsoft edge chromium based browser will same work with Edge? Help(microsoft edge)